# Play: Run tests with custom GuiceApplicationLoader

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, specs2

I have a CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader in which I am loading an environment specific conf file. When I run the tests in ApplicationSpec the values taken from the environment specific conf files are missing which supposedly means that my CustomApplicationLoader hasn't been executed.

Any idea how to pass the CustomApplicationLoader on to the FakeApplication or any other approach to read values from conf files during tests? Or even shouldn't this work out of the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found out that I can inject the custom GuiceApplicationLoader by passing it as an argument to the WithApplicationLoader like this:

```
    @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

  "My component" should {

    "load environment specific conf values loaded in by CustomApplicationLoader" in new WithApplicationLoader(new CustomApplicationLoader) {
        ...
      }
    }

}
```